# Как включить ждущий режим?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Ноутбук не хочет переходить в ждущий режим. При переходе тупо выключается. На 3 ОС такое происходит. Не происходило на Висте, которая стояла при покупке. После переустановки ОС перестало переходить. Ноутбук - Samsung R522. OS - Ubuntu 11.10. Походу что-то выключено в буте. Но что врубить-то?

Comment: ждущий это suspend или hibernate? десктоп какой ununtu unity/gnome, kde?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте поставить

```
add-apt-repository ppa:voria/ppa
```

[Подробности](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa).